# Seeking identity of mathematician in photo on the cover of "The Honors Class" by Ben Yandell

Tags: ho.history-overview, biography

All of the photos on the cover of Ben Yandell's book The Honors Class appear in the book, except the one in the upper left. I'd wager a beer that the mathematician in the upper left corner is A.N. Kolmogorov, but I'm not 100% certain. Anyone know for sure? Yandell died in 2004, so I can't ask him. I did a google search on Kolmogorov, and the photos shown are consistent with my guess, but none are identical.

There's a photo on the back of Busemann which isn't in the book, but the photo of Busemann which is in the book leaves little doubt that both photos are Busemann.

[image: Cover of Yandell - The Honours Class]

Comment: I tried a Google reverse image search, and the first suggestion was Mussolini.

Comment: It's definitely Kolmogorov. I was going to say that before seeing you mention it in your post.